# Change the view of popup tips when hovering the mouse over a method while debugging

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2022

This is the [perfect popup tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyErl.png)

This is the [popup tips during debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmWFT.png)

The question is рow to make it so that during the debug there was the same popup tip as in normal mode?

I tried googling, but I was probably choosing the wrong keywords and couldn't find a solution. I understand that it is somewhere in the settings, but I do not know where it is.

**UPD:**
Okay, I found out that thing I'm looking for is to change the default action in debug mode during "mouse on" action from Edit.ParameterInfo to Edit.QuickInfo.

Does anyone know where I can set it up? Actually I don't need Edit.ParameterInfo at all, so maybe there's a way to replace it by Edit.QuickInfo?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's no need to provide code. It's about UI of Visual Studio 2022